# Bug when evaluating a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string `calc`, which represents an operation (for example, `"2/2"`)

I want my code to evaluate the string and return the result.

When the string is invalid and cannot be evaluated (for example, `"2.2.2"`, I want to return `null`.

This is my code so far:

```
    const result = eval(calc);
    
    
    if (result === undefined){
      return null;
    } else {
      return result;
    }
```

My bug is: when the string is invalid as an operation and cannot be evaluated, I don't get `null`. Instead, the program throws an error.

How can I get `null` instead of an error?

Comment: First, please avoid using eval  ( see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!) why). Secondly use a proper `try ... catch` to catch an error and set your result accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `try/catch`

```
try {
    result = eval(calc);
    return result;
} catch (e) {
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `eval()` is often not necessary and can lead to [security and performance problems](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!). There is likely a better solution available. I advise you to explain your use case more detailed so we can help you find a better solution.

If you really want to do this you can use a try catch statement since an exception will be thrown when the code can't be evaluated.

```js
console.log(myEval("2.2.2"));
console.log(myEval("2/2"));

function myEval(str) {
  try {
    return eval(str);
  } catch {
    return null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

eval() will return an error when it cannot parse the command correctly.
When you use try and catch you can return null when an error occurred.

```
try{  
  const result = eval(calc);
  return result;
}
catch (error){
  return null;
}
```